# Spurious wakeups, wait() and notifyAll()

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have N threads that do these things in loop: increase shared variable, checks if shared variable value is N (if so put value to queue) and do wait(). I have one more threat that checks the q variable. If queue is true, it does notifyAll(). After that N threads should wake up, and do another run of loop. But it seems that some threads are waking up without notification. I've read about spurious wakeups, but I don't know what condition should I put to while() to check if it was spurious wake up.

Bellow is example of my code (not the same, but very similar in meaning):

Shared class is shared between all threads:

```java
class Shared {
    volatile int v = 0;
}
```

I create 10 threads and run them.

```java
class NThreads implements Runnable {
    private Shared shared;
    private QThread q;
    static int N = 0; /* N - number of threads */

    public NThreads(QThread q, Shared shared) {
        this.q = q;
        this.shared = shared;
        ++N;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0;i<1048575;++i) {
            doSomeCalculations();
            loop();
        }
    }

    private void loop() {
        synchronized (shared) {
            if (++shared.v == N) {
                shared.v = 0;
                synchronized (Q) {
                    q.q = true;
                }
                shared.wait();
            } else {
                shared.wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is only one QThread that waits for modification of q and then invoke notifyAll();

```java
class QThread implements Runnable {
    private Shared shared;
    volatile boolean q = false;

    public QThread(Shared shared) {
        this.shared = shared;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (;;) {
            if (q) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    q = false;
                }
                synchronized (shared) {
                    shared.notifyAll();
                }
            }
            doSomethingElse();
            // or even: Thread.yield();
        }
    }
}
```

Main class that runs everything:

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shared shared = new Shared();
        QThread qt = new QThread(shared);
        NThread[] nt = new NThread[10];
        for (int i=0; i<nt.length; ++i) {
            nt[i] = new NThread(qt, shared);
        }
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[nt.length+1];
        threads[0] = new Thread(qt);
        for (int i=0; i<nt.length; ++i) {
            threads[1+i] = new Thread(nt[i]);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<threads.length; ++i) {
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for (int i=0; i<threads.length; ++i) {
            threads[i].join();
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes there are threads (from NThreads) that finishes their loops, but other threads no. I think that is because of spurious wakeups. How to write condition to take cake of spurious wakeups and be sure that all threads can continue their work?

Maybe there is useful class in java.util.concurrent? But I didn't see anything interesting... :(

Comment: It's most likely _not_ spurious wakeups.  It's that your code is not doing what you intended.

Comment: I don't think this is all the code since in this example shared and q fields would be null.

Comment: How are the threads started?  How is `shared` and `Qthread` injected?

Comment: It's not clear atall what the goal of all this is. What are the threads waiting for? When you're at a bus stop, you're waiting for the bus. When you think it's coming, you double check it's the right bus, and wait again until the right bus comes. It's the same with threads. You need to wait until some condition becomes true. You could just make the notifying thread set a boolean value before notifyning, and have the other threads wait while this boolean is false.

Comment: Every NThread in loop does another things, but I didn't write it to not to obscure code. That "loop()" methods means "barrier" or "synchronize" in that place, so I'm sure that all threads done what they ought to and can do next step in calculations. My _real_ code is a much more **complicated and complex**.

Comment: I believe he is implementing a barrier object whereby each thread will execute one iteration of its loop, then wait for the other threads to also complete their iteration. Then do the next iteration etc. Java now has some barrier classes such as CyclicBarrier.

Comment: Yes, Darren, that could work. Thank you! But in my _real_ code the QThread is doing some network connection (or even local connection) and after that it can allow the NThreads to do next step of loop. What's more, size of NThreads can change, but it's easy to fix using CyclicBarrier - create new barrier with new count of parties.

Comment: `N` is 1 for all threads of course.  Each time `loop()` is called by the threads, the `shared.v` is incremented.  There is a chance that it == 1 but typically it won't.  Even if `N` was the thread-number like I guess you want there is a chance that `v` is 1 for thread-2 and 2 for thread-1 so neither will reset `v` to 0.  The code doesn't really make sense.  Maybe you should take a step back and explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You are right Gray. N is (_after edition of the code_) the count of all NThreads. For thread-1 `shared.v` can be 2, but only, when thread-2 increased `shared.v` to the 1. When I will have, for example, only two NThreads, after increasing `shared.v` by thread-1, that value is equal to N, so thread-1 will reset `shared.v` to 0. All I wanted to do is to be sure that all NThread will do the same step at the same time, and that QThread will tell to NThreads when they can do next step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaDocs for [Object.wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) discuss the spurious wakeup possibility. It also mentions that you should use the wait() in a loop that checks an external condition before leaving the wait loop.

You'll need to restructure the loop() method a bit to accomplish this

```
private void loop() {
    synchronized (shared) {
        shared.v++;
        while(shared.v < N) {
            shared.wait();
        }

        shared.v = 0;
        synchronized (Q) {
            q.q = true;
        } 
    }
```

In the end, you should probably find a concurrency library that has this built in since it's easy to get these types of things wrong. I'd look at Google's Guava, java.util.concurrency or one of the many Apache Commons libraries as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to all NThreads to invoke wait() and wait for notifyAll() from QThread. Condition `shared.v < N` is not good. But thank you for mentioning concurrency libraries. I will look for inspiration there.